# Zapier - Dynamic Dropdown as an Action Field, using values from the source

Tags: zapier

While writing a Zapier app, I have encountered the following problem.
My app, let us call id AppX is an app you send data to.

When creating a Zap, the user chooses whatever trigger (source) he wants, let's say he chooses Mailchimp.
Then the user chooses AppX, chooses an Action which we will call "Notify AppX" and then he has 2 Action Fields to fill up.

1. Dynamic Dropdown that I generate on my side, meaning I return the json constructing this dropdown.
2. Dynamic Dropdown of all the possible data fields from the trigger he chose.

Basically in 1. he chooses where to send the data to on my app and in 2. he chooses which data to send. I have implemented 1. but fail to implement 2.

Now I have no way of telling, which app he chose as a trigger and which fields of data they provide but still I want them to be able to choose multiple variables from that source and send it to me.

This is very similar to what the Klipfolio app does so if you know it, I'm trying to replicate its pattern on the Zapier platform.

If I can even limit (minimum and maximum) the number of data fields he chooses to send my app that would be even better.

How can I implement this step 2?